# Change Symbol in a paragraph using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ascii, symbols

I am trying to replace the symbol at the end of a paragraph, when some event happens. The original symbol is a square box ☐ and I use its ASCII in the code.

A sample Paragraph would be Problem No:1 ☐

This symbol is to be replaced by the symbol of a square box with a cross inside ☒

SO final paragraph would like Problem No:1 ☒

The routine to change the end symbol is as follows:

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[type=radio]', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var x = $(this).attr('id');
   var y = x.substring(17);
   var z = $("#QuestionBankLink"+y).text();
   var a = z.substring(0,13);
   var b = a + " &#9746;";
   $("#QuestionBankLink"+y).text(b);
});
```

As one can understand the id of the paragraph is QuestionBankLink followed by a number (basically a reference)

Now my problem is when the code is executed everything works fine except the fact that instead of symbol at the end I get the full set of characters of the ASCII. So what I get is:

Problem No:1 &#9746;

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Change `$("#QuestionBankLink"+y).text(b);` to `$("#QuestionBankLink"+y).html(b);`

The `.text()` method injects text exactly as it's in the string, with all tags and entities

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the substring to find the character and replace. In Jquery `replace` function you can directly provide the charecter to replace as given below.

```
$("#QuestionBankLink"+y).text($("#QuestionBankLink"+y).text().replace('☐','☒'));
```

I have attached a demo snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#replace').click(function(){
    $("p").text($("p").text().replace('☐','☒'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Problem No:1 ☐
</p>
<button id='replace'>
Replace
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `" &#9746;"` (or in hexadeciaml `" &#x2612;"`)

use `" ☒"` or `" \u2612"`

`&#9746;` is an HTML decimal numeric character entity reference. Characters in HTML are [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints.

`"\u2612"` is a JavaScript escaped [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals) for a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set.

`"☒"` is a JavaScript literal. It will work if your editor, saved file encoding, optional HTML meta charset tag, server's HTTP Content-Type charset header all line up, on, for example, UTF-8—which should not be a problem.

Of course, ☒, being a Unicode character, can be used in HTML, too.